# VBA (Visual Basic): ComboBox (Form Control) - Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: vba, excel, combobox, runtime-error

Just registered! (Even though I've used the site for few years lol!).

I am stuck with a problem on VBA, and its driving me crazy. Hopefully someone can solve my problem.

I am trying to reference a ComboBox(Form Control) I've added in Sheet6 manually. It contains several list of items. Then I will loop through each item in the combo box and do stuff with it..

However for the life of me I cannot understand what I am doing wrong?!

I keep getting the a run-time error '438':

[Object doesn't support this property or method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jkn5.png)

[This is the line the Run-time error occurs on:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToPIa.png)

```
Public Sub ReferralSummaries()

'Stop screen updates.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Method Variables
Dim Lstrw As Long
Dim CurrentWb As Workbook
Dim ReferralSheet As Worksheet
Dim ResultsSheet As Worksheet
Dim ReferralSheetCBox As Object

'Initialize Variables
Set CurrentWb = ThisWorkbook
Set ReferralSheet = CurrentWb.Sheets("Referral Breakdowns")
Set ResultsSheet = CurrentWb.Sheets("Results")
Set ReferralSheetCBox = Worksheets(6)

'Check Date column and update accordingly
Call Update_Date_Column(ReferralSheet, ResultsSheet)

For i = 0 To ReferralSheetCBox.ComboBox1.Items.Count - 1 **(ERROR TRIGGERED HERE).**
```

Any help is appreciated, please!

Kind Regards,
Ninja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use

```
Set ReferralSheetCBox = Worksheets(6).Shapes("ComboBox1")
```

Then you can access its properties via its `ControlFormat` property, for instance:

```
Dim nItems As Long
nItems = ReferralSheetCBox.ControlFormat.ListCount
```

hence your shown code last line would be

```
For i = 0 To ReferralSheetCBox.ControlFormat.ListCount - 1
```

Comment: Hi, I've declared a ControlFormat Property and started using this. This has enabled me to do what I was trying to do! I am confused as to why I can't just do Sheet6.ComboBox1? I created the ComboBox manually (It's form control and not ActiveX one).. I don't understand why I have to use the ControlFormat property vs simply doing Sheet6.ComboBox1? If you can help me understand, would be great.. I've seen other people simply do Sheet1.ComboBox1.. but I can't do that? Many Thanks for the solution btw..

Comment: I must admit I never digged into this and just accepted as it is...btw you may consider marking the answer as accepted. Thank you

Comment: I made a quick search and I can say that it must be related to the fact that an Excel Form Control is a Shape object containing a control. And this latter is accessed through ControlFormat property. On the other hand, an ActiveX control is a control itself so you can directly access control property and methods

Comment: Thank you for the info and for all the help, if you have a skype/discord please let me know, I can do with brainstorming for future tasks! Yes it works with ActiveX! It's still bizarre why people make use of the OleObject property though, and not directly do Sheet1.ComboBox1 for ActiveX combo boxes.. Maybe ill take a look at it later down the line. Also I think i need to rethink my code, and take the pivot table approach - but i am coming across some obstacles via the combo box + Table method. I may ask another Question shortly, please look out for it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use early-binding by strongly typing `ReferralSheetCBox` as a `DropDown` (which is a hidden type that encompasses ComboBox):

```
Dim ReferralSheetCBox As Excel.DropDown
```

And then set the reference to the shape's `DrawingObject`:

```
Set ReferralSheetCBox = Sheet6.Shapes("ComboBox1").DrawingObject
```

Then, you can adapt your code to:

```
For i = 0 To ReferralSheetCBox.ListCount - 1
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work :(. I've seen other people simply fetch the combobox object by using the dot operator on the combo box name. Sheet1.ComboBox1.. I don't understand why I have to go through all this Shape, DropDown properties? Any help is appreciated.. Although ControlFormat Property workaround worked for me for my combo box.. Read the upvoted comment!

Comment: You were quite specific about it being a ComboBox (Form Control). If you want to use the dot syntax and avoid the Shapes, you need to use the ComboBox (ActiveX Control) instead. Only the ActiveX controls are exposed as properties of the sheet.

Comment: Yes I just realised, ActiveX Control allows direct usage of the combo box on sheet6.combobox1. I was told Vice versa.. Thank you for the help though! Really appereciate the help.. Thinking now though I came across few obstacles which i doubt theres a work around for as its how excel is built.. So I may need to use Pivot Tables instead for what I want to achieve.. I may raise another Question, If you can look out for it and answer, that would be great!

Comment: Add me on skype/discord if you don't mind, can do with some VBA friends, contacts. Thank you for all the help!